DirectX exporter plugin for Blender 4?
Is there a plugin for exporting to .x for Blender 4? I've seen similar plugins for earlier versions but I don't think they'll work on 4

have you tried?

You might try this exporter in Blender 4.0.2: https://github.com/DodgeeSoftware/io_scene_directx It doesn't throw any errors, but I don't know if it works like you expect it to.
